# Ruby: Replace text content within HTML file with placeholders

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri, erb

I have a few HTML files with in-line styling and various HTML tags with text content. How (possibly using Nokogiri) can I replace the text content with place-holders, most likely converting the HTML into and ERB file with placeholders. These placeholders most likely will now be part of a key-value pair.

index.html

```
<html>
  <head><title>Sample Page</title></title>
  <body>
    <div style="margin-top:5px; margin-right:5px; margin-bottom:5px; margin-left:5px; font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt">
       <p style="">One line of text</p>
       <span class="hidden">New Span</span>
       <a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

becomes
index.html.erb

```
<html>
  <head><title><%= placeholder_1 %></title></title>
  <body>
    <div style="margin-top:5px; margin-right:5px; margin-bottom:5px; margin-left:5px; font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt">
       <p style=""><%= placeholder_2 %></p>
       <span class="hidden"><%= placeholder_3 %></span>
       <a href="www.google.com"><%= placeholder_4 %></a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

ERB makes things more 'Rails like' while using interpolation arguments may affect the structure.

Comment: can you show some sample input and what the desired output is

Comment: If you have just a few files, then the easiest/fastest way is to do it manually.